# Show up a dialog from external jsp page (Struts2, java)

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a form jsp page containing textfields and buttons and another jsp page that contains a dialog. I want to open the dialog with a click on the first page button.

**page1.jsp:**

```
<s:form namespace="/donneur" cssClass="row-fluid" 
    action="traiteClient">
        <label Class="control-label"><s:text name="DNAISS_TB" /></label>
        <s:textfield id="naissD" name="naissDonn"/>
        <button id="helpButton" class="btn btn-large" type="button"> <i class="icon-question-sign"></i> </button>
</s:form>
```

**page2.jsp:**

```
<sj:dialog 
        id="messageDialog" 
        autoOpen="false" 
        modal="true" 
        title='%{#titreForm}'
        width="auto"
        height="auto"
        cssStyle="color:%{message.couleur};font-size:%{getText('fontSize')}"

        buttons="{ 
            '%{getText('oui_val')}':function() { yesButton(); },
            '%{getText('non_val')}':function() { nobutton(); },
                }"
    >
  <center>  <s:property value="message.msg"/> </center>
    </sj:dialog>
```

I want to achieve that can someone help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a dynamic include:

```
<jsp:include page="page2.jsp" />
```

you may want (or not want) to make the included jsp hidden until later